# Hosting WordPress blog in subdirectory while app is hosted in AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

My React app is hosted on AWS and now I want to setup a WordPress blog in the subdirectory example.com/blog

I have already purchased Shared hosting from Namecheap. How can I achieve this so the app can be accessed from the app but example.com/blog will open the WordPress site.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a lot cleaner to separate them by subdomains instead of directories. If you had your blog at `blog.example.com` instead of `example.com/blog` then it would be as simple as pointing a new DNS record at your WordPress site.

If you really want to go the subfolder route, then you have a few options:

- Configure your app's web server software (Nginx, etc.) to proxy all requests to `/blog/*` to your WordPress site.
- Place some sort of proxy in front of both your application, and your WordPress site. On AWS you could configure a CloudFront CDN with multiple origins to act as this proxy.